# TYPO3 scheduler task - strange behavior

Tags: typo3, scheduler, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 6.2 and I created a custom extension with Extbase and Fluid.
I made a custom task in order to execute it every hour in the TYPO3 scheduler module. Below what it looks like :

```
<?php

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility;

class ImportCommandController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController {

    public function importCommand() {

    // some code

    }

}

?>
```

It seems to work fine, but the behavior is weird :

- if I execute manually the task : it works fine
- if I let the scheduler runs the task every hour : it doesn't work, th task stays stuck and after 24 hours, I get a error message in the Logs :

> [scheduler]: Removing logged execution, assuming that the process is
>   dead. Execution of 'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Scheduler\Task' (UID: 5) was
>   started at 2018-06-10 16:40:00

Then, I have to stop the task myself in the scheduler. According to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/3-Command-controllers.html), methods inside the class don't need to return true or false. So, why the task isn't successfull when launched by the scheduler ?

Comment: Did you use a CRON job at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a scheduler task like this

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extensionname\Task;

/***************************************************************
 *  Copyright notice
 *
 *  All rights reserved
 *
 *  ...
 *
 *  This copyright notice MUST APPEAR in all copies of the script!
 ***************************************************************/


/**
 * My scheduler task
 *
 */
class MyTask extends \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask  {


    /**
     * Execute, called by scheduler.
     *
     * @return bool TRUE if task run was successful
     */
    public function execute() {

        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::devLog(
            '[Vendor\\Extensionname\\Task\\MyTask]: Task run sucessfully', 'scheduler', 2);
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made this but the result is the same : if i execute manually it works, if it sets to automatic it never works. I try with a simple mail() func in my task, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

there are some differences between the scheduler task starting methods:

- scheduled by cron:
  it's CLI PHP which might be another version, at least another configuration than the PHP started by webserver (e.g. no time limit!), in TYPO3 it is executed with the special `cli-user`.
- started in the BE:
  this is started in the webserver context: (normaly) you have a time limit, the current TYPO3-BE user executes the task.

Comment: Hello Bernd, thanks but that doesn't give me any clue about my issue

Comment: you need to compare the PHP versions and it's configurations. try a simple task like writing php-info into a file, then compare the files from each call.

Comment: Both are 5.6.30

Comment: have you compared the configurations? try to save the info of phpinfo to a file and compare.

Comment: It seems that the issue is not because of differences between PHP version, but because of the command never returns true or false. Answer of Heinz Schilling works perfect.